# Read HTML from CSV and convert to dataframe

Tags: python, html, dataframe

I have a CSV file where one of the values is HTML code for a table:

```html
<table class='confluenceTable'><tbody>
<tr>
<th class='confluenceTh'>Fruit</th>
<th class='confluenceTh'>Colour</th>
<th class='confluenceTh'>Drink</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='confluenceTd'>Apple</td>
<td class='confluenceTd'>Purple</td>
<td class='confluenceTd'>Water</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to read in that value (string) and convert it to a full dataframe so that I can then reference to return all drinks, for example:

```
HTML_DataFrame['Drink']
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I've tried using the below but I'm finding that the entire table ends up within a single column of the new dataframe:

```
CSV_File = pd.read_csv(csv_file, index_col=None, header=0)
HTML = CSV_File['HTML_Data'][0]
HTML_DF = pd.read_html(HTML)
```